# exception encountered when calling layer"featurelayer"(type lambda) name k is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, tf.keras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93cdY.png)
I tried use "import tensorflow.keras.backend as K" and "from keras import backend as K" .
Both of them report the same mistake.

Here is the code.
def classification_net(datashape, num_classes):

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(datashape[1], datashape[2], datashape[3]))

x = layers.Conv2D(32, 7, strides = 2, activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)



x = resblock(x, 3, 32)
x = resblock(x, 3, 32)

x = resblock(x, 3, 64, first_layer = True)
x = resblock(x, 3, 64)


x = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)

x = layers.Flatten()(x)

x = layers.Dense(512)(x)


x = layers.Lambda(lambda  x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1), name = 'feature_layer')(x)

outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation= 'softmax')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

return model
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question.